# n@6.8.0: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module

Tags: reactjs

I run yarn install but I always got the following errors:

```
warning react-snap > mkdirp@0.5.1: Legacy versions of mkdirp are no longer supported. Please update to mkdirp 1.x. (Note that the API surface has changed to use Promises in 1.x.)
[2/4] Fetching packages...
error n@6.8.0: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because package n is not currently supported on windows.
Source: https://githubmemory.com/repo/tj/n/issues/656